# Completely hiding a whatsapp group so it never appears

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a whatsapp group which I have muted and disabled notifications for, but I have no way to completely hide it. When I archive it it appears when someone sends a message.

Comment: Why not simply leave it?

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp does not have such privacy mechanism as of yet, but if you use *Hike* you will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can archive the chat /delete group by long pressing the respective group